# Inheritance of 'super ' in python3

Tags: python

```
class A(object):
    def show(self):
        print 'A'

class B(A):
    def show(self):
        super(B,self).show()
        print 'B'

class C(A):
    def show(self):
        #A.__init__(self)
        super(C,self).show()
        print 'C'

class D(B,C):
    def show(self):
        super(D,self).show()

d=D()
print d.show()
```

Why is the result:

```
A
C
B
```

instead of:

```
A
B
C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this is exactly what you have asked) Reed more info on [c3 linearization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization). Short hint - super does not call parents method, instead it calls method, that corresponds to next class in linearized inheritance graph.

More specifically:

```
>>> D.mro()
0: [<class '__main__.D'>,
    <class '__main__.B'>,
    <class '__main__.C'>,
    <class '__main__.A'>,
    <class 'object'>
   ]
```

This `mro` thing is a list, through witch any method of class `D` that delegates its behavior to parents (sort of speak) would be pushed any time you call it. So you call `D().show()` - first it calls implementation of `show` in `D`, it does nothing but delegating this call further - to class `B`. Class `B` fist delegates this call to `C` (see the mro list) which delegates it further to `A`, which prints `"A"`, then `C` prints `"C"` and then `B` prints `"B"`.

You might ask - why `B` delegates to `C` instead of `A` (since `B` extends `A`, not `C`). This actually done on purpose, for more info have a look on this [great talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo)

Comment: I still dont get it... :(

Comment: @Jack1222 hope my update is usefull.

Comment: Its actually helpful for me, Thanks !!